# Double armour checks won't run together

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm on 1.16.5 and I'm trying to run two separate boot slot checks and for each boot a different jump boost level. They both work separately but I can't get them to run together.

I have a repeating clear block first:

```
/effect clear @p minecraft:jump_boost
```

Then my first chain command check:

```
/execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"pixelmon:rocket_boots"}]}] run effect give @p minecraft:jump_boost 2 1 false
```

And my second chain:

```
/execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"pixelmon:galactic_boots"}]}] run effect give @p minecraft:jump_boost 2 2 false
```

I've had them both with their own clear repeater, only one works and usually the one I activate last. I've had one clear with two chains, didn't work, I've tried numerous combinations and I cannot get this to work. Anyone have any insight into where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Is there any clear distinction of which one works and which one doesn't? Are the commandblocks all set to unconditional? Other than that, at first glance it looks good. It's not properly multiplayer compatible, but in singleplayer it should work. Also the execute is useless, you can just put the nbt check inside the effect command selector itself.

Comment: They are all unconditional yeah. When I have repeat clear > chain check and a second one the same for the other boots then the one I placed second works. If I place one repeat clear > chain check >chain check then the first check only works. I've messed around with it more and it seems to be the status effect that is causing problems, I switched to boots and legs, both with jump boost and didn't work but then changed to jump on boots and speed on legs and both worked. Thanks, I'll tidy it up later if I can get it working, having it written out like this helps me logic it out in my head lol,